# Changing confirmation page url dynamically after webforms submission

Tags: webforms, i18n-l10n

We have a single webform (Built using https://www.drupal.org/project/webform ) with a confirmation url of `/thank-you`

The same webform is displayed/used also if you originated from a translated page. So `http://example.com/form/enquire` is the same form for `http://example.com/en-US/form/enquire`

I need to be able to detect the en-US and instead forward onto `http://example.com/en-US/thank-you`

Is this possible through any hooks? This is a short term solution, we intend to translate the form ASAP but in the next day or so we need some solution which will do the above?

Regards
John

Comment: What is the Drupal version?

Comment: @AltaGrade - Nevermind, ty for response though. I translated the form etc and seems to be working fine now.